# Unity3D: creating an indoor scene e.g. classroom or dojo

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity3D. I've been going through all the tutorial materials. My question is how I should get started creating - or hopefully importing! - a 3D classroom scene or dojo (i.e. where people train martial arts) scene.

I should add a bit more info. My intention is to create a game within this setting/ambience, e.g. for the dojo, have two characters that will eventually fight each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you'd like to create a 3D indoor scene, you'll need to start by creating a 3D model of your scene. You can use free 3D modeling software like [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) to do this. If this is unfamiliar territory for you, you can see what downloadable options exist: [TurboSquid](http://www.turbosquid.com/)

You can drag and drop your models right into Unity3D if they're in the proper format. After that you can continue fleshing out your scene by adding [particle effects](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/ParticleSystems.html) and [lights](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Light.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'll start looking on TurboSquid for 3D models of the scenes I want. Any recommendations for file formats? E.g. 3ds, etc

Comment: .obj is fairly common. You should get the best results if you stick to it.

Comment: Great. Quick related question - would I be able to find online 3D models of characters than have animations for fighting? E.g. A character that can throw a punch or kick.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to find some. Free options may be limited but I'm so you can find enough for at least placeholders.